# Apache timing out

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I am running wampserver and have reinstalled the latest version today. Apache is reportedly running (although actually appears in the process list twice??) but when I visit a basic HTML or PHP page the page just can't load. It spins round and round and then crashes. I've been looking at this for the last hour and can't figure it out. I've reinstalled it, copied the icu.* files to apache\bin.

If I look in the resource monitor, I see httpd.exe and also an entry with - as the Image and PID? What could be causing Apache to be running but not serving up webpages - even basic ones?

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer/Apache/PHP/MySQL?

Comment: Have you looked in the Windows Event Viewer for messages from Apache?

Comment: My support team managed to fix it - I'm awaiting final clarification but it looks like that port 80 wasn't bound to the IP in the httpd.conf.